# Why gst_deinit freeze application?

Tags: windows, qt, gstreamer

OS: Windows 10

Gstreamer: 1.16.2

Qt: 5.14.0

I have application in QT, which use gstreamer. Now I would like to many times init and deinit gstreamer using:
`gst_init(NULL, NULL)` and `gst_deinit()`.

When I use `gst_deinit()` in my code, the application is freezed. When I debuq informations like this:

```
qInfo()<<"before";
gst_deinit();
qInfo()<<"after";
```

I see only "before" text.

What should I do to deinit gstreamer and don't freeze application?

EDIT should I use unref's functions?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a running pipeline you need to change its state to `GST_STATE_NULL` before calling `gst_deinit`, e.g.

`gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);`